# JavaFX: StackPane with scrolling capabilities when window too small

Tags: java, css, layout, javafx, fxml

In playing around with JavaFX, I've run into a layout problem that's got me stumped.

**I've been trying to find a way to create a container which can be resized, will centre any content if the container is larger than the content, or will enable scrollbars if the container is smaller than the content.** For my specific application, I want to be able to place a "loading" overlay over the whole UI, so have used the following combination of `Pane`s:

```
ScrollPane [yellow border] -> 
StackPane [magenta] -> 
(content Pane [cyan]), (loading overlay Pane [green])
```

The code below is a snippet of the closest I've managed without resorting to ugly hacks hard-coded in Java (ideally, this should all be done in FXML or perhaps CSS to maintain separation of layout from code).

The view produced by this code is:

[image]
The content (cyan outline) is centred, however it appears the `StackPane` (magenta) is expanding to the size of the `ScrollPane`'s width rather than it's *viewport* width, forcing the `ScrollPane` to always display scroll bars. The `StackPane`'s width *is* bound to the `ScrollPane`'s, so this is not particularly surprising, but it was the best I could come up with.

The setup *does* work as desired when the window is smaller than the content, at least (I'm not concerned about centring in this case):

[image: https://i.imgur.com/FLBOZEk.png]

**The question, then, is how can I achieve my desired layout: centred content in a resizable window which can scroll if required, using only FXML (and CSS at a push).**

Here's the code snippet(s):

Main.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader templateLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        templateLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/test.fxml"));
        Parent sceneRoot = templateLoader.load();
        TestController controller = templateLoader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(sceneRoot, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main.launch(args);
    }
}
```

TestController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TestController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scroll;
    @FXML
    private StackPane stack;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

test.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<ScrollPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101"
            fx:controller="TestController"
            fx:id="scroll"
            style="-fx-border-color: yellow">
     <StackPane fx:id="stack" prefWidth="${scroll.width}" 
                prefHeight="${scroll.height}" style="-fx-border-color: magenta">
        <GridPane alignment="CENTER" style="-fx-border-color: cyan"  
                  minWidth="200" maxWidth="200" minHeight="200" maxHeight="200">
            <!-- some dummy elements to populate the gridpane... -->
            <Text text="text 1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Text text="text 2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Text text="text 3" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        </GridPane>
        <ProgressIndicator minWidth="70" maxWidth="70" 
                           minHeight="70" maxHeight="70" style="-fx-border-color: lime"/>
    </StackPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: No time to test, but try `<StackPane fx:id="stack" minWidth="${scroll.viewportBounds.width}" minHeight="${scroll.viewportBounds.height}" style="...">`. You might need to do the binding in the controller, though, to avoid issues when the viewport bounds are null.

Comment: Did the binding in the FXML, and didn't get any errors, so that appears to be fine. Your solution is frustratingly close to working: on opening the application, it looks perfect. As one drags the edge of the window to resize it, however, every *second* pixel the scrollbars re-appear...

Comment: @James_D I'm surprised you didn't point to your excellent solution to this problem in [How may I zoom a Node centered in a ScrollPane?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2541811). I had this same issue a while back, and that's what helped me.

Comment: @MikaelF loaded that up, and it has the same issue (recorded it in action: https://gfycat.com/PleasingThickKudu ). Unless this is some issue with my environment? Running under Java SDK 1.8.0_101, on Windows 10, on a vanilla 1080p/100% scaling monitor, so I would hope that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @MikaelF Yeah. That's there... but it's a bit ugly (way too much code to achieve what it does). Thanks for linking it though.

Comment: @James_D I realise I didn't mention you in the original reply -- any thoughts on the scrollbar strangeness? See my previous comment, or here: gfycat.com/PleasingThickKudu . (As a side-note: I was using the wrong installation of the Java SDK previously, too, switched to 1.8.0_121 which made no difference).